# Chromversion upgrade to V116 I am gettting error in my test

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Chromversion upgrade to V116 I am getting error in my test  I have tried using selenium version 4.12.0 n 4.11.0

```
<properties>        
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
   <poi.version>3.9</poi.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- dependencies for framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.50.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- WebDriverManager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version\>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- TestNG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.21</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies\>
```

Comment: Edit your question and share your code and error stack from the console. Also indent the code so that others can read it properly.

Comment: 1. use latest chrome drivers https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable<br> 2. use selenium manager https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/ 3. provide code where issue occur

Answer (score 0):

Please try to following steps:

- Update the selenium version to 4.12.0
- Clear the chrome driver cache if you have older versions in this path (In windows path is C:\Users<user name>.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win32
- I can see you have already upgraded the io.github.bonigarcia

This worked for me. 2nd action was the issue I had after I updated the versions